# Ошибка "FAILED to execute appendchild on node parameter 1 is not of type node"

Tags: javascript, dom

```
this.onload = () => {
    let can = document.querySelector("#can");
    for (let i = 0; i < 80; i++) {
        let c;
        circle = document.createElement("div");
        circle.classList.add("circle");
        can.appendChild("circle");
    }
}
```

Я пытаюсь добавить класс `circle` на класс `can`, но отображается ошибка

> FAILED to execute appendchild on node parameter 1 is not of type node

Comment: вообще, в ошибке сказано, что `can.appendChild` ожидает не текст (`"circle"` - это текст), а `Element`. т.е. в appendChild нужно передать _переменную_ circle (без кавычек)

Answer (score 0):

Неверное использование метода .appendChild. И вообще не верная формулировка. can у вас не "класс", а DOM элемент:

```
let can = document.querySelector("#can")
```

А метод Node.appendChild добавляет дочерний DOM элемент в тот DOM элемент на котором он вызван.
Т.е. не понятно о чем идет речь. Если вам нужно добавить новый DOM элемент внутрь элемента "can" то используйте метод Node.appendChild и передавайте туда DOM элемент который необходимо добавить.

```
can.appendChild(document.createElement('div'))
```

А если к элементу can необходимо добавить именно класс "circle" то можно использовать Node.classlist:

```
can.classlist.add("circle")
```